# remove apostrophe from string python

Tags: python, string

I'm trying to remove the apostrophe from a string in python.

Here is what I am trying to do:

```
source = 'weatherForecast/dataRAW/2004/grib/tmax/'
destination= 'weatherForecast/csv/2004/tmax'

for file in sftp.listdir(source):
    filepath = source + str(file)
    subprocess.call(['degrib', filepath, '-C', '-msg', '1', '-Csv', '-Unit', 'm', '-namePath', destination, '-nameStyle', '%e_%R.csv'])
```

filepath currently comes out as the path with wrapped around by apostrophes.
i.e.

```
`subprocess.call(['', 'weatherForecast/.../filename')]`
```

and I want to get the path without the apostrophes
i.e.

```
subprocess.call(['', weatherForecast/.../filename)]
```

I have tried `source.strip(" ' ", "")`, but it doesn't really do anything.

I have tried putting in `print(filepath)` or `return(filepath)` since these will remove the apostrophes but they gave me
 syntax errors.

```
filepath = print(source + str(file))
               ^
```

SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I'm currently out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you add the exact errors and exception stack trace you get?

Comment: Those apostrophes mean you're dealing with a `string`, so they aren't really _in the string itself_... How exactly is that a problem?

Comment: Your question is very confusing. Is the "wrong" format displayed by a `print`? Or are you wanting to pass the unquoted value to `subprocess.call` directly? Because the latter _will_ fail.

Comment: The program needs to run a directory without the single apostrophes. Currently, subprocess.call('', filepath) comes out as subprocess.call('', 'weatherForecast/.../file'). I need it come out as subprocess.call('', weatherForecast/.../file)

Comment: @user3886109 What are you expecting `weatherForecast/.../file` to be in Python terms? Are you aware that the quotes around the string aren't included in the actual call? For eg `subprocess.call(['ls','/'])` will run `ls /` and not `ls '/'`...

Answer (score 1):

The `strip` method of a string object only removes matching values from the ends of a string, it stops searching for matches when it first encounters a non-required character.

To remove characters, replace them with the empty string.

```
s = s.replace("'", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer to this question is actually wrong and can cause lots of trouble. `strip` method `removes as leading/trailing characters`. So you use it when you have character to remove from start and end.

If you use `replace` instead, you will change all characters in the string. Here is a quick example.

```
my_string = "'Hello rokman's iphone'"
my_string.replace("'", "")
```

The above code will return `Hello rokamns iphone`. As you can see you lost the quote before s. This is not someting you would need in your case. However, you only parse location without that character I believe. That's why it was ok for you to use at that time.

For the solution, you are doing just one thing wrong. When you call `strip` method you leave space before and after. The right way to use it should be like this.

```py
my_string = "'Hello world'"
my_string.strip("'")
```

However this assumes that you got `'`, if you get `"` from the response you can change quotes like this.

```py
my_string = '"Hello world"'
my_string.strip('"')
```